# Correctness and meaning of "zero tolerance regarding child safety"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is an excerpt from IKEA Singapore's Facebook page:

> A third party investigation has shown that the locking mechanism is
>   not reliable, posing a risk for young children, despite approved tests
>   to applicable standards.
>       “At IKEA, we have **zero tolerance regarding child safety**. We want to offer safe and healthy products and we think that children are the
>   most..."

I am interested to know if the choice of words as "zero tolerance regarding child safety" is correct. In different contexts for example "zero tolerance towards sexual harassment" seems correct, since sexual harassment is a negative thing. But child safety on other hand is positive, so why would one show zero tolerance towards it?

Comment: It says _"zero tolerance **regarding** (not **towards**) child safety"_. It is okay.

Comment: So, you're asking about the difference between "towards" and "regarding?"

Comment: @NVZ I'm not sure I agree. We say: *zero tolerance* for something "negative" or harmful. For example, "XYZ has zero intolerance of / for / toward / towards  /exam (or) examination malpractice." To say "we have zero tolerance towards candidates who respect the rules" is pretty daft, if you ask me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You misread my comment. *Regarding* is not equal to *towards*, is what I said. *"Zero tolerance **towards** something negative"* is correct. "*Zero tolerance **regarding** something positive (or negative)"* can be correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your comment needs editing. Replace "intolerance" with "tolerance" in "XYZ has zero.."

Comment: @NVZ  after 5 mins it's too late to edit comments... the other two examples are correct tho'. I'm still doubtful whether you can have *zero tolerance "regarding" sth positive*. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's extremely rare and I would not encourage using it that way. *"Zero tolerance regarding safety rules"*

Comment: If "child safety" is a defect category its not positive and the sentence is fine.  They might have a nonzero or "six sigma tolerance" for other categories such as colorfastness, packaging accuracy, etc. That are less important or easy to correct.

Comment: I think what they mean to say is that they have zero tolerance for the ***disregard*** of child safety. But I think it’s readily apparent what is meant with their current wording.

Comment: This sense of "tolerance" requires a culprit.  You don't exhibit tolerance for good or positive results, only results that are negative. IKEA's word choice just doesn't work. In typical PR style, word choice avoids even the hint of agency. But with "zero tolerance", the reader is sent on a hunt for the agent. What ever IKEA was trying to say, It doesn't work for me. @Jim 's fix is a good one.  It supplies an implied disregard-er.

Comment: I do not see an actual problem to be solved here. There is nothing grammatically wrong with the excerpt; nobody seems confused about what it means, either. This question is an invitation to criticize the wording. Please see the [help], especially the section on what kind of questions not to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence. "Zero [tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance)", in engineering and statistics, means "allowing no deviations from the standard".  It does not imply that the standard is enforcing a positive or negative attribute.

The term has been "hijacked" in several contexts to have more specific meanings, but the above use in not in one of those contexts.

The one "defect" in the statement is that the authors, having IKEA's engineering bent, were insensitive to the specialized meanings, leading to confusion.

Comment: Zero tolerance is not here an engineering term. It's a sociological term meaning that something is not tolerated at all. 'Zero tolerance for bullying' means that no bullying is allowed, not even a little bit.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Then explain what the sociological term "locking mechanism" means.

Comment: Just because one part of the paragraph uses an engineering term doesn't mean all of it is about engineering. Any good engineer also knows zero engineering tolerance is an impossibility.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Just because "zero tolerance" has sociological meanings in some contexts does not imply those meanings for every context, especially a context which contains **no other sociological reference**.  And, speaking as an engineer, I know that "zero tolerance" **does** have an engineering meaning.

Comment: Wikipedia considers the sociology to be the main meaning.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Wikipedia is not an authoritative source.

Comment: @PhilSweet - The second paragraph means that the term (which is fundamentally engineering/statistical) has been used in non-engineering/non-statistical contexts, and, in those contexts, new meanings and inferences have been applied.  But those uses are unrelated to the use in the subject statement.  (How is this not clear?)

Comment: @PhilSweet - "Tolerance" was an engineering/statistics concept well before the social "zero tolerance" usage appeared.

Comment: From [1965](https://books.google.com/books?id=TjWtKEGtY-gC&q=%22zero+tolerance%22&dq=%22zero+tolerance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy0tL82MnNAhUh6IMKHdoPA08Q6AEIIzAB):  *FDA has set a zero tolerance for certain pesticides in or on certain food products.*  Not until 1985 do I see the term being used in the social sense (to refer to tolerance for discrimination).

Comment: I understand your point now. You are treating "zero tolerance" as a fixed phrase. I wasn't, and that's why I didn't understand the whole hijacking bit.

Answer (score 1):

'Zero tolerance ' is a term used to mean something is not tolerated at all. The term is common enough to have it's own [Wikipedia entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_tolerance).  It's normally used for something negative. A city with 'zero tolerance for speeding' means every case of speeding will be punished, no matter how small.

This phrase is a clumsy way of stating that, presumably to avoid the even clumsier 'zero tolerance for products or practices that might reduce child safety'. It's pretty likely that's what it means though. In other words they will not accept any compromise on child safety.